# send request to a tls 1.2 web server in node soap

Tags: ssl, soap, request, node-soap

I need to send request to a web server which is TLS 1.2 in [node soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)
any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the secureOptions with a constant on the ClientSSLSecurity method.

```
var constants = require('constants');

client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
    '/path/to/key',
    '/path/to/cert',
    '/path/to/ca-cert',
    {
        strictSSL: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        hostname: 'some-hostname',
        secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2,
        forever: true,
    },
));
```